# Boost ptree array of numbers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I use the following code to create an array of the numbers.

After running the following code, I reveive the following results:

```
{
    "": "1.100000",
    "": "2.200000",
    "": "3.300000"
}
```

It is good except for my desired result has to be an array of numbers not string. Adding a number directly by `boost::property_tree::ptree(x)` gives me an error too. How can I produce my output json results?

```
{
    "": 1.100000,
    "": 2.200000,
    "": 3.300000
}
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    std::vector<double> Vec={1.1,2.2,3.3};
    for(double x:Vec)
    {
        std::string x_string=std::to_string(x);
        pt.push_back(
            std::make_pair("", 
            boost::property_tree::ptree(x_string)) );

    }
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(std::cout, pt);
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use pt.put() ?

Comment: @pSoLT, `put` does not recognize empty path.

Comment: you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PTree has no such features.

Everything is text in the serialized formats. Even if the chosen backend format *could* support (limited) typed data.

Documentation [proof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser):

[image]

As I keep re-stating:

> Boost does **not** have an XML library.
>
> Boost does **not** have a JSON library.
>
> Boost has a Property Tree library. It deals with Property Trees. Not JSON, XML or whatever else.

Comment: That is a little disappointing. It is nice to have properties of the exact type, and use ===, not == in the javascript. I was hoping to change over to using the BOOST property tree for all my JSON. Now, I am not sure.